# Set the column width in GANTT view

Tags: jquery, gantt-view

When the GANTT view is being used, how could one resize the columns using jQuery without using the generated controlid ([like in this example](https://aajtechblogs.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/adjust-the-column-width-of-a-project-tasks-view-of-a-project-site-in-sharepoint-2010/))?  I'm looking for a way to do this in a re-usable javascript function.

I'm thinking to be able to find a control that has `ListViewWebPartJSGrid` in its id. It is possible that there would be more than one on the page, but that would work out.

**[update]**

Okay, I figured out how to fetch the control id (you can see the color change):

```
var $trackingGridID = $("[id$=_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable]").attr("id");
$('#' + trackingGridID).css("background-color", "blue");

//this will fetch:  ctl00_ctl21_g_c3e5fead_d466_4448_9648_dcb92778921d_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable
```

Now that I have the ID, it is a matter of figuring out how to modify the column widths...

But I want to do something like this:

```
function SetColumnWidths(column1, column2, column3)...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, got it.

First, fetch the dynamic controlid.  For our purposes, the non-dynamic part of it is `_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable`, so we'll jQuery that.

```
var $trackingGridID = $("[id$=_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable]").attr("id");
$('#' + trackingGridID).css("background-color", "blue");
```

> //this will fetch: 
>   ctl00_ctl21_g_c3e5fead_d466_4448_9648_dcb92778921d_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable

---

Fetch the Column by index (to change the colour, you have to modify the various `a` properties)

```
var thiscolumn = $('#' + trackingGridID + " th[role='columnheader']:eq(0)");    
$(thiscolumn).css("width", "400");
```

Fetch a row by index:

```
var thisrow = $('#' + trackingGridID).find("tr:eq(2)"); 
$(thisrow).css("background-color", "blue");
```

Fetch a particular cell by index:

```
var thiscell = $('#' + trackingGridID).find("td:eq(6)");
$(thiscell).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Of course, to change the width, you just add this to the vars:

```
.css("width", "400");
```

---

**The Function**

```
SetGanntColumnWidth(0, 400)  //set the first column's width
SetGanntColumnWidth(2, 350)  //set the third column's width

//The third parameter is optional in case the idpart changes
function SetGanntColumnWidth(whatcolumn, whatwidth, whatidpart){
    if(!whatidpart)
        whatidpart = "_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable";
    var thisid = $("[id$=" + whatidpart + "]").attr("id");
    var thiscolumn = $('#' + thisid + " th[role='columnheader']:eq(" + whatcolumn + ")");

    $(thiscolumn).css("width", whatwidth);
    $(thiscolumn).children().css("width", whatwidth);   
}
```