# Resizing columns in a Gantt view

Tags: script-webpart

were can I find a script that will allow me to set the column width in a GANTT view fore SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){$("div.ms-vh-div:contains('Description')").css("width", "350px");});
```

Place this code in content Editor web part and you can set the SharePoint column width in view's.

Otherwise [reference this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72885/set-the-column-width-in-gantt-view)