# Gantt presentation in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, gantt-view

Has anyone come across a render or CSS that can be applied to the OOTB SP 2013 Gantt charts?

In my view, the whole left-hand construct of the chart looks really very tacky. I don't need this section to move, and the column title section could be much more presentable IMO.

**UPDATE:**

I have found this site quite helpful in controlling some of the gantt elements.

[Set the column width in GANTT view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72885/set-the-column-width-in-gantt-view)

Moving ahead, I am wanting to block the leftpane from click events.

The following code blocks the right side pane from clicks, but not the left hand side. Any suggestions on what I can use to block those events?

```
var whatidpart = "_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane_mainTable";
var thisid = $("[id$=" + whatidpart + "]").attr("id");
var yy = '';
$("[id=WebPartWPQ2]").css("pointer-events:none;");
$("[id=WebPartWPQ2]").off('click');
$("[id=WebPartWPQ4]").css("pointer-events:none;");
$("[id=WebPartWPQ4]").off('click');
$("[id$=" + whatidpart + "]").css("pointer-events:none;");
$("[id$=" + whatidpart + "]").off('click');
var whatridpart = "_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_rightpane_mainTable";
$("[id$=" + whatridpart + "]").css("pointer-events:none;");
```